# NoClassDefFoundError GANT script on Grails

Tags: java, grails, groovy, classpath, gant

I'm trying to build some GANT script prior to my Grails Plugin.
Basicly, i want to extend DefaultGrailsTemplateGenerator Class with new Class which add new method to auto generate service class by Grails Templating scheme.

Suppose i've named my class with Service generator which extends DefaulGrailsTemplateGenerator and add generateService method.

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.scaffolding.DefaultGrailsTemplateGenerator;

class ServiceGenerator extends DefaultGrailsTemplateGenerator {
        void generateService(GrailsDomainClass domainClass, String destdir) {
        }
}
```

All things went normally (e.g GANT Script was called), except in a line of code which i instanstiated ServiceGeneratorClass, it returns error :

```
Error Error executing script GenerateService: com.cygnus.grails.util.scaffolding.ServiceGenerator
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.cygnus.grails.util.scaffolding.ServiceGenerator
    at GenerateExt_groovy.class$(GenerateExt_groovy)
    at GenerateExt_groovy.$get$$class$com$cygnus$grails$util$scaffolding$ServiceGenerator(GenerateExt_groovy)
    at GenerateExt_groovy.generateForDomainClass(GenerateExt_groovy:81)
```

I've tried to browse on this error and try to call the class by change the syntax from :

```
def templateGenerator = new ServiceGenerator(classLoader)
```

to :

```
def myClass = classLoader.loadClass("org.my.ServiceGenerator")
```

Still i found the java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError .
I still couldn't figure out why this thing could happen.
Can someone help me ?

I attach my GANT Script which calls up Service Generator

```
/**
 * Gant Script for generating Service Class based on Artifact
 * This Script was used for auto generate service class which is needed to handle basic transactional statements such as:
 * - AuditTrail for tables
 * - Logging before insert / update on tables
 */
includeTargets << grailsScript("_GrailsCreateArtifacts")
includeTargets << new File("${myPluginPluginDir}/scripts/GenerateExt.groovy")



target ('main': "Generates the CRUD service for a specified domain class") {
    depends(checkVersion, parseArguments, packageApp,classpath,configureProxy, 
            loadApp, configureApp, compile)

    promptForName(type: "Domain Class")
    generateViews = false
    generateForName = argsMap["params"][0]
    generateForOne()
}
setDefaultTarget(main)
```

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: I am struggling with the same problem. I think this is the way to go but i don't had the time to try it yet: [Using your application classes inside Grails Gant script](http://groovytard.blogspot.com.ar/2010/10/using-your-application-classes-inside.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally done!

This is an example of what you want to do: [grails-flex-scaffold-script](https://github.com/burtbeckwith/grails-flex-scaffold/blob/master/scripts/_FlexScaffoldCommon.groovy)

And this is my implementation:

*change $userInterfacePluginDir for your plugin name

Put this files in scripts:

GenerateService.groovy

```
includeTargets << grailsScript("_GrailsInit")
includeTargets << grailsScript("_GrailsCreateArtifacts")
includeTargets << new File("$userInterfacePluginDir/scripts/_GrailsGenerateService.groovy")

target ('default': "Generates the service for a specified domain class") {
depends(checkVersion, parseArguments, packageApp)
promptForName(type: "Domain Class")
generateForName = argsMap["params"][0]
generateServiceForOne()
}
```

_GrailsGenerateService.groovy

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.GrailsDomainClass;
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.scaffolding.*
import org.springframework.core.io.AbstractResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource;
import grails.util.GrailsNameUtils

/**
 * Gant script that generates a service for a given domain class
 *
 * @author Martín Caballero
 *
 */

includeTargets << grailsScript("_GrailsBootstrap")

generateForName = null

target(generateServiceForOne: "Generates service for only one domain class.") {
    depends(loadApp)

    def name = generateForName
    name = name.indexOf('.') > 0 ? name : GrailsNameUtils.getClassNameRepresentation(name)
    def domainClass = grailsApp.getDomainClass(name)

    if (!domainClass) {
        grailsConsole.updateStatus "Domain class not found in grails-app/domain, trying hibernate mapped classes..."
        bootstrap()
        domainClass = grailsApp.getDomainClass(name)
    }

    if (domainClass) {
        generateServiceForDomainClass(domainClass)
        event("StatusFinal", ["Finished generation for domain class ${domainClass.fullName}"])
    }
    else {
        event("StatusFinal", ["No domain class found for name ${name}. Please try again and enter a valid domain class name"])
        exit(1)
    }
}

def generateServiceForDomainClass(domainClass) {
    UserInterfaceTemplateGenerator = classLoader.loadClass('plugin.ui.scaffold.UserInterfaceTemplateGenerator')
    def templateGenerator = UserInterfaceTemplateGenerator.newInstance(classLoader)
    templateGenerator.grailsApplication = grailsApp
    templateGenerator.pluginManager = pluginManager

    event("StatusUpdate", ["Generating service for domain class ${domainClass.fullName}"])
    templateGenerator.generateService(domainClass, basedir)
    event("GenerateServiceEnd", [domainClass.fullName])
}
```

UserInterfaceTemplateGenerator: (helper class - extends DefaultGrailsTemplateGenerator)

```
package plugin.ui.scaffold

import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.scaffolding.DefaultGrailsTemplateGenerator;
import grails.build.logging.GrailsConsole
import grails.util.BuildSettingsHolder
import groovy.text.SimpleTemplateEngine
import groovy.text.Template
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.GrailsApplication
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.GrailsDomainClass
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.GrailsPluginManager
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.PluginManagerAware
import org.springframework.context.ResourceLoaderAware
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource
import org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource
import org.springframework.core.io.ResourceLoader
import org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver
import org.springframework.util.Assert
import org.springframework.core.io.AbstractResource
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.scaffolding.SimpleDomainClassPropertyComparator
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.scaffolding.DomainClassPropertyComparator

class UserInterfaceTemplateGenerator extends DefaultGrailsTemplateGenerator {
    public UserInterfaceTemplateGenerator(ClassLoader classLoader){
        super(classLoader)
    }

    void generateService(GrailsDomainClass domainClass, String destdir) {
        Assert.hasText destdir, "Argument [destdir] not specified"

        if (domainClass) {
            def fullName = domainClass.fullName
            def pkg = ""
            def pos = fullName.lastIndexOf('.')
            if (pos != -1) {
                // Package name with trailing '.'
                pkg = fullName[0..pos]
            }

            def destFile = new File("${destdir}/grails-app/services/${pkg.replace('.' as char, '/' as char)}${domainClass.shortName}Service.groovy")
            if (canWrite(destFile)) {
                destFile.parentFile.mkdirs()

                destFile.withWriter { w ->
                    generateService(domainClass, w)
                }

                LOG.info("Controller generated at ${destFile}")
            }
        }
    }

    void generateService(GrailsDomainClass domainClass, Writer out) {
        def templateText = getTemplateText("Service.groovy")

        boolean hasHibernate =pluginManager?.hasGrailsPlugin('hibernate')
        def binding = [pluginManager: pluginManager,
                       packageName: domainClass.packageName,
                       domainClass: domainClass,
                       className: domainClass.shortName,
                       propertyName: getPropertyName(domainClass),
                       comparator: hasHibernate ? DomainClassPropertyComparator : SimpleDomainClassPropertyComparator]

        def t = engine.createTemplate(templateText)
        t.make(binding).writeTo(out)
    }

    protected canWrite(File testFile) {
        if (!overwrite && testFile.exists()) {
            try {
                def response = GrailsConsole.getInstance().userInput("File ${makeRelativeIfPossible(testFile.absolutePath, basedir)} already exists. Overwrite?",['y','n','a'] as String[])
                overwrite = overwrite || response == "a"
                return overwrite || response == "y"
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                // failure to read from standard in means we're probably running from an automation tool like a build server
                return true
            }
        }
        return true
    }

    protected String getPropertyName(GrailsDomainClass domainClass) { "${domainClass.propertyName}${domainSuffix}" }

}
```

And, finally, this is my template: (Put it in src/templates/scaffolding/)

Service.groovy

```
<%import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.GrailsClassUtils;%>
<%=packageName ? "package ${packageName}\n\n" : ''%>
class ${className}Service {

    def getTable() {
        def query = {
            <%
                def searchFields = GrailsClassUtils.getStaticPropertyValue(domainClass.clazz, 'search' )
                if(searchFields)
                {
            %>
                    if (params.q) {
                        or{
                        <%searchFields.each { field ->%>
                            ilike("${field}", '%' + params.q + '%')
                        <%}%>
                        }
                    }
            <%  }   %>
            if (params.sort){
                order(params.sort,params.order)
            }
        }
        def criteria = ${className}.createCriteria()
        return criteria.list(query, max: params.max, offset: params.offset)
    }
}
```

Then, you use the command as "grails generate-service yourdomainclass"

Hope that helps!

This is the essential of the answer:

```
UserInterfaceTemplateGenerator = classLoader.loadClass('plugin.ui.scaffold.UserInterfaceTemplateGenerator')
def templateGenerator = UserInterfaceTemplateGenerator.newInstance(classLoader)
```

Comment: I will try it as soon as possible and will get you informed. Thanks for your reply and effort :-)

Comment: It is working for me. I change this a little for refactoring some things but the code is fine. You can change the template of service the way you like. My script now accept a plugin argument for generate the service in the specified plugin (for modularized apps in plugins).

Comment: I also submit a patch in Jira for doing this: [generate-service](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-9131)